# Android L Preview actionbar color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/theme.html) I should be able to change the color of my ActionBar if I define a primary color in my style.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

However the color is still the grayish default color. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a values-21 folder... I made the changes in the values folder and of course it has not been used.

Answer (score 5):

As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/theme.html#statusbar) say, you should use `@android:style/Theme.Material` as your parent theme, not `android:Theme.Material`.

Then you should be able to use `<item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>` like you did already.

Comment: Thank you! As I said: I used the wrong values folder. Now it works even with "android:Theme.Material". I guess it's just a shortcut for "@android:style/Theme.Material"

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this as your parent theme in **res/values-v21** folder:

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Material" />
```

Then refer to it in your styles file like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Sample" parent="Theme.Base" />
```

Comment: You can also use the AppCompat v7 library if you want older versions of the platform to display a material design theme as well.